# Using Three-state logic to speed up floating point multiplication

Tags: boolean-algebra, tri-state, arithmetic-division

This question is idle pondering but...

Given "double-precision" is 53 bits, so takes 53^2 (or 2809) largely ordered sequential operations to perform multiplication.  Whereas the equivalent ternary is 33 "trits" and takes only 33^1.58 (or 255) Ternary multiplication operations (cf. [Karatsuba algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm))... and considering...

- Binary can (in part) be sped up with a nibble "look up table".
- But **all** Ternary ops can all be done in parallel silicon.

I find (even ignoring balance ternary parallelism potential) that ternary multiplication is **11 times faster** then double precision binary multiplication.

So given that most chips actually use "[Three-state logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic)" leads me to this question...

**Question:** Does any CPU/chip out there do a *ternary* (or sneaky binary conversion to ternary) to harvest this 10 times improvement in speed?

(BTW: I'm guessing that ternary addition is only 30% faster, if the numbers are of the same sign, and 50% faster if of different signs)

Comment: A lot of claims and no peer reviewed publications referenced here. (Yes, a Wiki. But seriously, that's not a technical paper on the topic.) If your claim about "done in parallel" silicon is correct -- and I can't say since I've never read a paper on this topic -- then I'd have to guess such a method must use balanced ternary (as a one-digit multiplication has no carry to deal with.) But what do I know? Provide some serious background material to check. duskwuff correctly points out your error in imagining that tri-state logic has anything to do with your claims. It doesn't. Different thing.

Comment: I'm thinking that if anyone's **Answer** includes a description of the Soviet "Setun" computer that **actually** used balanced-ternary "a long time ago", then their answer will get accepted.  It could be a "sad misinterpretation" to post that paired MOSFET cannot do ternary logic,  unless the poster specifically references a peer reviewed publication backing up the assertion.  Recall my original post hints that "This question is idle pondering" ... so I continue to welcome pondering.

Comment: Cmos is 'tri state' but in this sense: one of p/n channel on or both off. Allows you to 'wire-or'.

Comment: "TLC (Tri Level Cell) NAND takes the MLC concept one step further. By creating more states in the memory cell, you can effectively store 3 bits per cell." cf. [NAND Flash Data Storage Overview - SLC, MLC and TLC](http://embedded-computing.com/news/nand-slc-mlc-tlc)

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing tri-state signalling with ternary logic.

There is no efficient way of implementing ternary logic in a modern CMOS microchip. Tri-stated ("floating") signals cannot be used as a third state; a floating signal that is not pulled either high or low will behave unpredictably. (In most situations, gate capacitance within the chip will cause it to remain in whatever state it was last.)

Comment: The Soviet "Setun" used balanced ternary a long time ago. No idea how someone would instantiate it today, if they cared to try. Not, as you point out, as a tristated output in any case. And I'm pretty certain any hypothetical advantages would be far and away washed out in practice by the gap between any such serious implementation of primitives and the current, high state of modern CMOS technology using binary.

Comment: This is the right answer. The assumption that most processors make "three-state logic" is a sad misinterpretation of what tri-state   I/O means. Even if a processor can accept a "tri-state input", by the time it enters the core, this input has been evaluated as either a '0' or a '1'. So the assumption is wrong. There is no processor in the market that implements three-state logic inside its core.

Answer (score 1):

The Karatsuba algorithm works fine on binary numbers too.  In fact it should work fine no matter what base your number system uses.

The multiplication and addition algorithm will still have the same order regardless of which base your number system uses.  you can't really speed them up by using a number system with a higher base.

The reason is that computing each of the basic addition and multiplication operations on each digit will require increasingly complex circuits the higher the number system base.  For example a ternary half adder will take way more transistors than a binary one, and those extra transistors will translate into more propagation delay and slower clock speeds.

Answer (score 1):

See the other answers and comments, tri-state is not a short cut to ternary representation.

If you look up the literature on fast adders, you find that operation in higher bases *is* used, to shorten the carry chain. For instance base 4 is quite common, using a very conventional 2 binary bits per tetrigit (one source suggests 'crumb' for a quaternary digit, by the extension of byte down through nybble). Higher base is routine in FFTs, using base 4, base 8, and sometimes a mixed 4 and 2. You'll notice all bases are simple powers of 2, as it's a royal pita to operate in hardware on any other representation. That's not to say non-binary bases can't be used in hardware when they *need* to be used, just that you need an overwhelming motivation to do it.